# Does firebase auth UID expires or not?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, backend

I'm goning to use `auth.UID` in my backend web service as api_key for each user

I wounder if `UID` is final key or it expires/changes

[image]

Comment: the user id will not expire, but the access token will

Comment: perfect, thank you @AmanGrover

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `auth.UID` will never expire. One thing to keep in mind is that the `auth.UID` will always be the same only if the user does not delete his account. If you let the users the possibility to delete their accounts, if they will sign in again into your app, another `UID` will be generated, which will be different from the first one. Not every time the UID is a good solution for identifying a user.

Answer (score 5):

I addition to @AlexMamo answer, I found that **auth.UID** expires when app's data is cleared in scenario when user **is signed in anonymously**. (note: uninstalling clears app's data too)

Could not comment due to reputation points.