# Does the firebase user uid change if the user is signed out of the app when using email authentication?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I have to implement firebase email authentication and want to store data with a field of firebaseUser.uid in that. I want to know if there is any case when the user's uid will be changed so that I don't mess up with the user data as I will be referring it based on the user's uid. So if any user signs up using an email id, it's uid should never change unless he logs in again with a different email.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/45505131 too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The UID for a user is assigned randomly and never changes within that project.

Comment: UID can change if the user is deleted from the project manually.